# How to convert a Swift 5.7 Regex back to a string?

Tags: swift, regex, reflection, swift-regexbuilder

It's pretty straightforward to convert a string to a regex:

```swift
let regex = try! Regex("foo")
```

But if I try to get the string back out of the regex, instead of `foo`, I get something like:

> `_StringProcessing.Regex<_StringProcessing.AnyRegexOutput>(program: _StringProcessing.Regex<_StringProcessing.AnyRegexOutput>.Program)`

Mirrors are of marginal help here. It takes several levels of reflection to get anywhere:

```swift
let regexMirror = Mirror(reflecting: regex)
let program = regexMirror.children.first!.value // runtime type: Regex<AnyRegexOutput>.Program
let programMirror = Mirror(reflecting: program)
print(Array(programMirror.children))
```

> `[(label: Optional("tree"), value: _StringProcessing.DSLTree(root: _StringProcessing.DSLTree.Node.convertedRegexLiteral(_StringProcessing.DSLTree.Node.concatenation([_StringProcessing.DSLTree.Node.convertedRegexLiteral(_StringProcessing.DSLTree.Node.atom(_StringProcessing.DSLTree.Atom.char("f")), _StringProcessing.DSLTree._AST.ASTNode(ast: ｢f｣)), _StringProcessing.DSLTree.Node.convertedRegexLiteral(_StringProcessing.DSLTree.Node.atom(_StringProcessing.DSLTree.Atom.char("o")), _StringProcessing.DSLTree._AST.ASTNode(ast: ｢o｣)), _StringProcessing.DSLTree.Node.convertedRegexLiteral(_StringProcessing.DSLTree.Node.atom(_StringProcessing.DSLTree.Atom.char("o")), _StringProcessing.DSLTree._AST.ASTNode(ast: ｢o｣))]), _StringProcessing.DSLTree._AST.ASTNode(ast: (｢f｣,｢o｣,｢o｣))))), (label: Optional("compileOptions"), value: _StringProcessing._CompileOptions(rawValue: 0)), (label: Optional("_loweredProgramStorage"), value: nil)]`

This is something that gives the appearance of being parseable, but it's full of private types and things I don't particularly care about.

Is there a simple way to get the string representation of a regex?

Comment: After going through the documentation it doesn't look like there is any way to do this.